# Greater than using date on the database vs date today using Next/ReactJS

Tags: next.js

I'm currently having an issue while filtering the data on my app. Here's the below code:

```
                                {(dateNow <= newsData.endDate) ?
                                    <>
                                    </>
                                    :
                                    <>
                                        <Col xs={12} md={12} mb={12}>
                                            <FormGroup  className="px-3">
                                                <Row>
                                                    <Col xs={12} md={12} mb={12}>
                                                        <h5><b className="text-primary">{newsData.category}</b>: <b><a href={newsData.link} className="text-danger">{newsData.title}</a></b></h5>
                                                    </Col>
                                                </Row>
                                                <b >Description:</b> {newsData.description}
                                                <br/><b>Posted by</b> <a href="#">{newsData.createdBy}</a> on <b>{newsData.createdOn}</b>.
                                            </FormGroup>
                                        </Col>
                                    </>
                                }
```

I'm using NextJS. My date format is YYYY-MM-DD. My problem is some of the data still shows in my page even though I've already filtered them using: **dateNow <= newsData.endDate**

It seems that the system is confused or don't know how to filter them since they were modified to that format. I need your help to resolve this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```html
  const checkDate = (endDate) =>{
    const GivenDate = new Date(endDate);
    const CurrentDate = new Date();
    CurrentDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    if(GivenDate  >= CurrentDate) {
      return false
    } else { return true}
  }

{checkDate(newsData.endDate) === true ?
```